# Error parsing JSON after updating php file. Works before PDO, now JSON parsing error

Tags: java, php, android, sql, json

Through chrome i can log in using a member from the database (MySQL), and i can make a new user. When i use the app, i can make a new user but the app crashes.

Using simple php (below) i get a proper response, and the new activity is launched. The problem here is both correct and incorrect credentials work.

```
<?php
$response = array();
if (isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])) {
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "User Name and password are set";
} else {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "User Name and password not set";
}
echo json_encode($response);
```

The following is my login.java file:

```
package com.amity.paul.amity;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import library.JSONParser;

public class login extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    private EditText user, pass;
    private Button mSubmit, mRegister;

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // JSON parser class
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    //php login script location:

    //localhost :
    //testing on your device
    //put your local ip instead,  on windows, run CMD > ipconfig
    //or in mac's terminal type ifconfig and look for the ip under en0 or en1
    // private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://xxx.xxx.x.x:1234/webservice/login.php";

    //testing on Emulator:
    private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://10.0.2.2/amity/login.php";

    //testing from a real server:
    //private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://www.yourdomain.com/webservice/login.php";

    //JSON element ids from repsonse of php script:
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        //setup input fields
        user = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
        pass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);

        //setup buttons
        mSubmit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login);
        mRegister = (Button)findViewById(R.id.register);

        //register listeners
        mSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);
        mRegister.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.login:
                new AttemptLogin().execute();
                break;
            case R.id.register:
                Intent i = new Intent(this, register.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        boolean failure = false;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(login.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Attempting login...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Check for success tag
            int success;
            String username = user.getText().toString();
            String password = pass.getText().toString();
            try {
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

                Log.d("request!", "starting");
                // getting product details by making HTTP request
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                        LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);

                // check your log for json response
                Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

                // json success tag
                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());
                    //save user data
                    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(login.this);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = sp.edit();
                    edit.putString("username",username);
                    edit.commit();

                    Intent i = new Intent(login.this, home.class);
                    finish();
                    startActivity(i);
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                }else{
                    Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;

        }
        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
            pDialog.dismiss();
            if (file_url != null){
                Toast.makeText(login.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

    }

}
```

I then changed the php to be more advanced, as below:

```
<?php   
$response = array();
if (isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])) {  
    require("config.inc.php");
    try {
        $query = " 
            SELECT 
                id, 
                username, 
                password
            FROM users 
            WHERE 
                username = :username
            AND password = :password
        ";

        $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute(array(':username' => $_POST['username'],
                                       ':password' => $_POST['password']
                         ));
        if($stmt->rowCount() == 1){
            $response["success"] = true;
            $response["message"] = "user found";        
        }else{
            $response["success"] = false;
            $response["message"] = "user not found";
        }
    }
    catch (PDOException $ex) {
        $response["success"] = false;
        $response["message"] = "Database Error1. Please Try Again!";
    }

} else {          
    $response["success"] = false;         
    $response["message"] = "User Name and password not set"; 
}
echo json_encode($response);
```

Problem now is parsing error. Logcat:

```
08-16 15:39:40.620      841-856/com.amity.paul.amity E/JSON Parser﹕ Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value  of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
08-16 15:39:40.630      841-856/com.amity.paul.amity W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3a21ba8)
08-16 15:39:40.670      841-856/com.amity.paul.amity E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: com.amity.paul.amity, PID: 841
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.amity.paul.amity.login$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(login.java:117)
            at com.amity.paul.amity.login$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(login.java:97)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Please make the solution 'noob friendly' as I am new to android app development. Thanks!

Edit:

I fixed the issue using the following php:

```
<?php   
$response = array();
if (isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])) {  
    require("config.inc.php");
    try {
        $query = " 
            SELECT 
                id, 
                username, 
                password
            FROM users 
            WHERE 
                username = :username
            AND password = :password
        ";

        $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute(array(':username' => $_POST['username'],
                                       ':password' => $_POST['password']
                         ));
        if($stmt->rowCount() == 1){
            $response["success"] = true;
            $response["message"] = "user found";        
        }else{
            $response["success"] = false;
            $response["message"] = "user not found";
        }
    }
    catch (PDOException $ex) {
        $response["success"] = false;
        $response["message"] = "Database Error1. Please Try Again!";
    }

} else {          
    $response["success"] = false;         
    $response["message"] = "User Name and password not set"; 
}
echo json_encode($response);
```

One last issue, in logcat, it will tell me if success = true / false. How can i make a message appear to say incorrect credentials, and if the right combo is entered, to launch the new activity?

Comment: 1. you should ask yourself what error/exception you get ... 2. then you should ask yourself where and why ... i'm pretty sure that with those 2 steps there would be no this question here at all ... NullPointerException here is only becuase you "ate" an error in `jsonParser.makeHttpRequest` and return null ... so the real problem   is JSONException ... ok ... we are getting closer ... now you should dump the http response ... then analyze(how you could get it from your PHP code) the response

Comment: Hum.. What did you changed exaclty in order to make it work? I couldn't see any difference between the original and the edited PHP code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the ':' char in the array you're pasing to `prepare()`:

```
$result = $stmt->execute(array('username' => $_POST['username'],
                               'password' => $_POST['password']
```

Because otherwise PDO would return an empty response or worse, a "Warning" or "Error" php statement that will add up before the JSON you're generating at the end, and thus generate a parsing exception. Your php response would look like:

```
Error in line BLA BLA BLA ...
["success": "false", "message":"blablabla"]
```

Which you would unable to parse with your Java app.

So it's not actually an issue in your Android code!

The ':' in the request means "check in the given array the value after ':'".

Comment: Thank you for the tips. I am not home yet so i will give you a response when I get back. Cheers man.

Comment: @PaulGerardAli Ok! Please keep me up to date because Osman Mutlu doesn't seem to have spotted the same issue as me, so I'm curious :)

Comment: i have made it work with the above code (added at the end). have a look at the following question as I still need help with that. Thanks!

Comment: Well, there are several ways to display a message to the user:
Toast, or AlertDialog (and that's just my two favourites).
Have a look [there for Toast](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html) and [there for AlertDialogs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html). Both are pretty easy and straightforward to use if you know you Object Oriented basics. I would recommend Toast for such thing, and it's super easy to use.

Comment: Cheers for the quick response. Appreciate it (Y)

Comment: Regarding the new Activity, the way to do that in Android is called 'Intent'. Have a look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html). This is only way to perform such action, and needs some pre-reading and comprehension. I would strongly advise you to read some tutorials and the documentation I linked you to get started with it. As always in Android, it's not _that_ difficult but it just needs a good level of comprehension to manage everything fine.

Comment: And last thing, you need to be clear with the [Android Activity LifeCycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html) so that the transitions between the Activity goes smoothly and as expected. I tell you that because I had some unforeseen issue while programming an app on my currently dev device. When I skipped to another device, the whole app when glitchy because I didn't managed my lifecycle properly (especially pausing and restarting Activities...). You're welcome! Cheers, and keep on coding :D

Comment: Look at my .java file though...   Intent i = new Intent(login.this, home.class);
                    finish();
                    startActivity(i); ....activity doesnt start

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59683/discussion-between-rems-and-paul-gerard-ali).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the second php code is for login, I didn't use isset function before but you can use this code. It's really straightforward.

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
//gets user's info based off of a username.
$query = " 
        SELECT
            username, 
            password
        FROM login 
        WHERE 
            username = :username 
    ";

$query_params = array(
    ':username' => $_POST['username']
);

try {
    $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
}
catch (PDOException $ex) {
    // For testing, you could use a die and message. 
    //die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());

    //or just use this use this one to product JSON data:
    $response->{"success"} = 0;
    $response->{"message"} = "Database Error";
    die(json_encode($response));

}

//This will be the variable to determine whether or not the user's information is correct.
//we initialize it as false.
$validated_info = false;

//fetching all the rows from the query
$row = $stmt->fetch();
$login_ok = false;
if ($row) {
    //if we encrypted the password, we would unencrypt it here, but in our case we just
    //compare the two passwords
    if ($_POST['password'] === $row['password']) {
        $login_ok = true;
    }
}

// If the user logged in successfully, then we send them to the private members-only page 
// Otherwise, we display a login failed message and show the login form again 
if ($login_ok) {

    $response->{"success"} = 1;
    $response->{"message"} = "Login Succesfull";
    die(json_encode($response));
} else {
    $response->{"success"} = 0;
    $response->{"message"} = "Wrong Password";
    die(json_encode($response));
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the tips. I am not home yet so i will give you a response when I get back. Cheers man.

Comment: I used the above code that i have added to the end of the question. Have a look, as I still need help with the question below the new code. Thank you for your answer though, appreciate it!